# Fortran interface with C types

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have the following which I'm trying to compile with gfortran 9:

```
module eiface
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

  implicit none

  abstract interface
    function AlertMessage(atype, szFmt)
      integer(c_int32_t) :: atype
      type(c_ptr(c_char)) :: szFmt
    end function
  end interface

  ...
```

I believe the interface is meant to go after the `implicit none` but I get the following error:

`Error: Parameter 'c_int32_t' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression`

If I get rid of the C types then it compiles fine.

Is there a way to use C types here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `import` the C datatypes from the module scope into each subroutine of your interface (remember that in Fortran, single subroutines have no external dependencies by default):

```
  abstract interface
    function AlertMessage(atype, szFmt)
      import c_int32_t,c_ptr ! Import C datatypes from module into this interface
      integer(c_int32_t) :: atype
      type(c_ptr) :: szFmt
    end function
  end interface
```

Answer (score 1):

**An interface body is a separate scope** and the `USE` (and other specifications) in the module do not apply to it. To use (in this case) `iso_c_bindings` in the interface body, you must put the `USE` statement *in* that same interface body.

Also in Fortran's C-interop you don't declare pointer-to-specific-type as in C; you have *one* Fortran type `TYPE(C_PTR)` which corresponds to all C object pointer types, and *one* `TYPE(C_FUNPTR)` which corresponds to all C function pointer types (remembering that in C 'function' includes both value-returning and non-value-returning, i.e. the equivalent of both Fortran `FUNCTION` *and* `SUBROUTINE`).

Finally, if this is actually a C (or C-compatible e.g. C++ `extern "C"`) routine you are interfacing to, it should also specify `BIND(C)`.

```
module eiface
  abstract interface
    function AlertMessage(atype,szFmt) ! bind(c)?
      use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
      integer(c_int32_t) :: atype
      type(c_ptr) :: szFmt
    end function
  end interface
end module
```